# What happens if I have switched the Time Machine off?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, time-machine, backup

Im using the MacBook Pro Retina and currently using an external hard drive to store many datas using the Time Machine, i.e: songs, images, movies, docs and so on. I was wondering what will happen if I switched TIME MACHINE off? I have backed up everything to my external hard drive though and currently my storage in the macbook is showing 29.01gb BACKUP, I was thinking if by switching the Time Machine could it allow more space on my disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are local snapshots. They should be on your external hard drive if it has been connected. Switched Time Machine off will remove them, but new backups will be created, unless you disable them.

The following answer contains links which explain this very clearly https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/178718/19086

Comment: Thank You Milliways, I have done as you said and it did show difference in space. Thanks once again. I will turn the Time Machine back once I am backing up again